# Passing Complex real and imag by reference

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, complex-numbers, rvalue

**The Problem:** C++11 has made some changes to complex numbers so that `real()` and `imag()` can no longer be used and abused like member variables.
I have some code that I am converting over that passes `real()` and `imag()` to `sincosf()` by reference. It looks a little like this:

```
sincosf(/*...*/, &cplx.real(), &cplx.imag());
```

This now gives a `error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand`

which error was not received prior to c++11.

**My Question:** Is there an easy inline fix? or do I have to create temporary variables to get the result and then pass those to the complex number via setters?

Thanks

Comment: Umm ... from the C++03 standard [lib.complex] `T real() const; T imag() const;`, so those functions never returned lvalues. Either your old stdlib implementation or your old compiler was non-conforming.

Comment: I am on 98... we are a little far behind

Comment: You can use `reinterpret_cast` to obtain pointers to the real and imaginary parts.  `std::complex` is the one case I know of where the standard actually guarantees this to work.

Comment: @Praetorian yeah, you're right... Apparently the gcc version 4.8.2 of complex is "not a conforming implementation" that returns a reference prior to c++11

Comment: You can of course simply write a wrapper around `sincosf`, or a wrapper around `std::complex`...

Comment: `std::polar` might not be a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do

```
cplx = std::polar(1.0f, /*...*/);
```

Comment: `polar` is cos in real and sin in imaginary, which is the reverse from the question (sin in real part, cos in imaginary part).

Comment: @T.C. `std::polar(1.0f, pi/2 - /*...*/);` then. Though I suspect OP actually just wants `polar`.

Answer (score 3):

As T.C. [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245014/passing-complex-real-and-imag-by-reference-c11#comment48591195_30245014) in the comments, the standard allows you to `reinterpret_cast` `std::complex` to your heart's content.

From N3337, *§26.4/4 [complex.numbers]*

> If `z` is an lvalue expression of type *cv* `std::complex<T>` then:
>   — the expression `reinterpret_cast<cv T(&)[2]>(z)` shall be well-formed,
>   — `reinterpret_cast<cv T(&)[2]>(z)[0]` shall designate the real part of `z`, and
>   — `reinterpret_cast<cv T(&)[2]>(z)[1]` shall designate the imaginary part of `z`.
>   Moreover, if `a` is an expression of type *cv* `std::complex<T>*` and the expression `a[i]` is well-defined for an integer expression `i`, then:
>   — `reinterpret_cast<cv T*>(a)[2*i]` shall designate the real part of `a[i]`, and
>   — `reinterpret_cast<cv T*>(a)[2*i + 1]` shall designate the imaginary part of `a[i]`.

So make the following replacement in your code

```
sincosf(/*...*/, 
        &reinterpret_cast<T*>(&cplx)[0], 
        &reinterpret_cast<T*>(&cplx)[1]);
```

Comment: While this is a more direct answer, yuri's provides a much cleaner result.

Answer (score 0):

Do not that declaring temporaries still is a good option and should be just as efficient as what you are previously doing, given a good optimizing compiler (say, `gcc -O3`).

See the resulting assembly from `gcc -O3` here: https://goo.gl/uCPAa9

Using this code:

```
#include<complex>

std::complex<float> scf1(float x) {
  float r = 0., i = 0.;
  sincosf(x, &r, &i);
  return std::complex<float>(r, i);
}

void scf2(std::complex<float>& cmp, float x) {
  float r = 0., i = 0.;
  sincosf(x, &r, &i);
  cmp.real(r);
  cmp.imag(i);
}

void scf3(std::complex<float>& cmp, float x) {
  float r = 0., i = 0.;
  sincosf(x, &cmp.real(), &cmp.imag());
}
```

Where `scf2` is equivalent to your statement, you can see very similar assembly in the three cases.

```
scf1(float):
    subq    $24, %rsp
    leaq    8(%rsp), %rsi
    leaq    12(%rsp), %rdi
    call    sincosf
    movss   12(%rsp), %xmm0
    movss   %xmm0, (%rsp)
    movss   8(%rsp), %xmm0
    movss   %xmm0, 4(%rsp)
    movq    (%rsp), %xmm0
    addq    $24, %rsp
    ret
scf2(std::complex<float>&, float):
    pushq   %rbx
    movq    %rdi, %rbx
    subq    $16, %rsp
    leaq    8(%rsp), %rsi
    leaq    12(%rsp), %rdi
    call    sincosf
    movss   12(%rsp), %xmm0
    movss   %xmm0, (%rbx)
    movss   8(%rsp), %xmm0
    movss   %xmm0, 4(%rbx)
    addq    $16, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    ret
scf3(std::complex<float>&, float):
    pushq   %rbx
    movq    %rdi, %rbx
    subq    $16, %rsp
    leaq    8(%rsp), %rsi
    leaq    12(%rsp), %rdi
    call    sincosf
    movss   12(%rsp), %xmm0
    movss   %xmm0, (%rbx)
    movss   8(%rsp), %xmm0
    movss   %xmm0, 4(%rbx)
    addq    $16, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    ret
```